# How to iterate multiarray on jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jquery array

[image: Jquery Object]

I am trying to iterate it, but I always get only the first value [false, false] and the cycle ends

I am using this function to iterate

```
function CompareAndShowOrHide(url) {
    var elem = jQuery(".vanessa_content .block-title");
    $.each(url_array , function( index, obj ) {
        $.each(obj, function( key, value ) {
            console.log(key);
            console.log(value);
        });
    });
}
```

With no success, any help would be appreciated thanks

Jsfiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/xvcg0spz/

Comment: Your jsfiddle seems a bit incomplete.  Generally, though, $(obj).each(function(){}) is the syntax I use with jquery.  I couldn't tell what your function was hoping to do as the url parameter you pass in is not used in the function.

Comment: Is not finished, I am more worried about the array iteration right now, I just want to compare actual url vs the ones on the array @JECarterII

Comment: OK, in that case, you might want to use the incoming url parameter in some way.  I don't see it referenced in your CompareAndShowOrHide function.

Answer (score 0):

You declare url_array as an array,

```
var url_array = [];
```

but are not using it as one. Arrays take numerical indexes, javascript does not have associative arrays (arrays that take strings as an index).

So doing the following:

```
url_array['/'] = [false, false]; 
url_array['/cart'] = [true, false]; 
url_array['/checkout/34'] = [true, false];
```

You are setting properties on the array object, and not adding anything to the array. So your array is empty. Since it is an instance of array, jQuery will treat it as such and try to access the array elements and not the properties you have set.

Simply declare url_array as an object instead and jQuery will iterate over the properties correctly

```
var url_array = {}; //you should probably rename it since its not really an array
```

**Demo**

```js
var url_array = {};
url_array['/'] = [false, false]; 
url_array['/cart'] = [true, false]; 
url_array['/checkout/34'] = [true, false]; 
url_array['/user/register'] = [true, true];
url_array['/checkout/34/checkout'] = [true, false];
url_array['/checkout/34/review'] = [true, false];
url_array['/product-categories/aaaa11'] = [false, false];
url_array['/product/54/38'] = [false,false];
url_array['/our-stores'] = [true,false];
url_array['/user'] = [true,true];
url_array['/news'] = [false,false];
url_array['/Shows'] = [false,false];
url_array['/content/Biography'] = [false,false];

function CompareAndShowOrHide(url) {
  $.each(url_array , function( index, obj ) {
    $.each(obj, function( key, value ) {
      console.log(key);
      console.log(value);
    });
  });
}
CompareAndShowOrHide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem, basically, is that jQuery.each is treating url_array as an array, because that's how you defined it. But it's treating it as an array with a length of 0, so it never bothers to iterate over anything.

The values you stored in there are associated with properties of the array--they're not array elements the way you're thinking of them. You might want to look into associative arrays in JavaScript.

There's an easy solution, though. You just need to define your "array" as what it really is: an object.

```
var url_array = {};
```

You'd then iterate over them with the object version of jQuery.each:

```
    $.each(url_array, function(key, value) {

    });
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z37ctLx4/2/).